# AngularFire Missing or insufficient permissions on login, works after refresh

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I have a very standard Angular 12 application where a user logs in with Firestore and can then perform CRUD operations over their own documents.

As soon as you login to the application it throws

```js
core.mjs:6495 ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at index.esm2017.js:4327
    at ns (index.esm2017.js:4325)
    at to.onMessage (index.esm2017.js:11273)
    at index.esm2017.js:11227
    at index.esm2017.js:11250
    at index.esm2017.js:15093
    at index.esm2017.js:15126
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:25853)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371)
```

and no documents are loaded. However if I just refresh the page the error goes away and the documents load as expected.

My auth service is very standard

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthService {
  
  constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {

  }

  public login() {
    signInWithPopup(getAuth(), new GithubAuthProvider())
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to load the `Firestore` documents in a `RepositoryService`

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class RepositoryService {

  repositories$: BehaviorSubject<Repository[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Repository[]>([]);

  constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth, private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(authUser => {
      if (authUser) {
        this.firestore
          .collection("user")
          .doc(authUser.uid)
          .collection<Repository>("repositories")
          .valueChanges()
          .subscribe(this.repositories$);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Is a different instants of `AngularFireAuth` being used here or something?

What's interesting is if I sign out, then refresh the page and log back in things work as expected. However signing out and straight back in again causes the `Missing or insufficient permissions` exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the error by replacing the standard subscription with a `switchMap`

```js
constructor(
  private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private firestore: AngularFirestore,
) {
  this.angularFireAuth.authState
    .pipe(
      switchMap((authUser) =>
        authUser
          ? this.firestore.collection('user').doc(authUser.uid).collection<Repository>('repositories').valueChanges()
          : of([])
      )
    )
    .subscribe(this.repositories$);
}
```

I think the root of the problem was with the firebase listener trying to fetch documents during/after the logout process which was causing it to error out.

This would explain why refreshing the page between login sessions solves.

Awkward.